# Return rows only if all items of category are True

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

After some work, I managed to simplify a dataframe that looks like the following:

```
Category | Boolean
A | True
A | True
A | False
B | True
B | True
C | True
C | True
B | False
D | True
C | True
```

Now, I would like to obtain the rows which categories only have True in column 'Boolean'. Another way of saying this would be: return rows only that for a given category only True is present in column 'Boolean'.

From the example DF above, I would be looking to obtain:

```
Category | Boolean
C | True
C | True
D | True
C | True
```

No row with category A or B should be returned because at least one of the rows with this categories has a False. However, since for categories C and D all rows were True, we should return all rows with these categories.

In my real dataframe there are more columns but none of them is unique and none of them is relevant for slicing it. If you do need an extra column for your solution please make up one instead of using index, if possible but not essential.

Hope it is clear enough. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that your `Boolean` column is really of dtype `bool` (and not strings), you could use `groupby` with `transform`:

```
>>> df.loc[df.groupby("Category")["Boolean"].transform(all)]
  Category Boolean
5        C    True
6        C    True
8        D    True
9        C    True
```

which works because we have

```
>>> df.groupby("Category")["Boolean"].all()
Category
A    False
B    False
C     True
D     True
Name: Boolean, dtype: bool
```

and so

```
>>> df.groupby("Category")["Boolean"].transform(all)
0    False
1    False
2    False
3    False
4    False
5     True
6     True
7    False
8     True
9     True
Name: Boolean, dtype: bool
```

Comment: it works thank u! May I ask what is the 'transform' method? I couldn't find it on pandas or numpy documentation.

Comment: @Anderson: `transform` takes the results of the groupby and "broadcasts" it back up to the indices of the original dataframe.  It's explained in the introduction to [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html).

Answer (score 0):

`x=df.groupby(df.category).aggregate(np.all)` should create a data frame whose left column are the individual types and the right column is true if all items are true.

`x[x.Boolean]` could return only those categories which are true.

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/groupby.html